# filtering dictionary based on value in a key

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I would like to filter the dictionary that has 'hometown':'NY'

```
[{'name': 'paul', 'age': '26', 'hometown': 'AU', 'gender': 'male'},
{'name': 'mei', 'age': '27', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'female'},
{'name': 'smith', 'age': '14', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'male'},
{'name': 'raj', 'age': '13', 'hometown': 'IND', 'gender': 'male'},.....]
```

here is my code

```
a=[]
for test in result:
   x={}
   for key,value in test.items():
        if key == 'hometown':
            if 'NY' in value:
                x[key] = value
   a.append(x)
```

this is my output:

```
[{}, {'hometown': 'NY'}, {'hometown': 'NY'}, {}]
```

my desired output would be:

```
[{'name': 'mei', 'age': '27', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'female'},
{'name': 'smith', 'age': '14', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'male'}]
```

Comment: Just use a list comprehension with a condition: `[d for d in l if d['hometown'] == 'NY']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [12]: a = [{'name': 'paul', 'age': '26', 'hometown': 'AU', 'gender': 'male'},
    ...:
    ...: {'name': 'mei', 'age': '27', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'female'},
    ...: {'name': 'smith', 'age': '14', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'male'},
    ...: {'name': 'raj', 'age': '13', 'hometown': 'IND', 'gender': 'male'}]

In [13]: [i for i in a if i["hometown"]=="NY"]
Out[13]:
[{'name': 'mei', 'age': '27', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'female'},
 {'name': 'smith', 'age': '14', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'male'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
result = [{'name': 'paul', 'age': '26', 'hometown': 'AU', 'gender': 'male'},
{'name': 'mei', 'age': '27', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'female'},
{'name': 'smith', 'age': '14', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'male'},
{'name': 'raj', 'age': '13', 'hometown': 'IND', 'gender': 'male'}]

a=[]
for i, test in enumerate(result):
    for key,value in test.items():
        if key == 'hometown':
            if 'NY' in value:
                a.append(result[i])
print(a)
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'mei', 'age': '27', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'female'}, {'name': 'smith', 'age': '14', 'hometown': 'NY', 'gender': 'male'}]
```