# Filter dict in a list with the same value

Tags: python

I would like to filter the dictionary that has 'hometown':'NY'

```
[{'name': 'paul', 'age': '26', 'hometown': '98_street_AU', 'gender': 'male'},
{'name': 'mei', 'age': '27', 'hometown': '19_street_NY', 'gender': 'female'},
{'name': 'smith', 'age': '14', 'hometown': '7_street_NY', 'gender': 'male'},
{'name': 'raj', 'age': '13', 'hometown': '56_street_IND', 'gender': 'male'},.....]
```

here is my code to filter the dictionary and the output

```
a=[]
for test in result:
   x={}
   for key,value in test.items():
        if key == 'hometown':
            if 'NY' in value:
                x[key] = value
   a.append(x)
print(a)


[{}, {'hometown': '19_street_NY'}, {'hometown': '7_street_NY'}, {}]
```

my desired output is

```
[{'name': 'mei', 'age': '27', 'hometown': '19_street_NY', 'gender': 'female'},
{'name': 'smith', 'age': '14', 'hometown': '7_street_NY', 'gender': 'male'}]
```

Comment: Haven't you asked exactly the same question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62908505/filtering-dictionary-based-on-value-in-a-key? What was wrong with the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple method:

```
a=[]
for i in result:
    if i['hometown'].__contains__("NY"):
        a.append(i)
print(a)
```

Comment: I love your method as it is much simpler. But what if I want to filter dict that does not contain NY? But I don't want to use if/else. Does python have a special syntax like `__contain__`?

Comment: So basically what my if condition does is, it returns a true/false for the given condition. Checking whether the condition is false and executing should do the work. Something like this:

if i['hometown'].__contains__("NY") == False: 

If you like my answer please upvote it and mark it as a verified answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension with `str.endswith`

**Ex:**

```
a = [test for test in result if test.get('hometown', "").endswith('NY')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding only item `hometown` not the dictionary. This should work:

```py
a=[]
for test in result:
   x={}
   for key,value in test.items():
        if key == 'hometown':
            if 'NY' in value:
                a.append(test)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [6]: a = [{'name': 'paul', 'age': '26', 'hometown': '98_street_AU', 'gender': 'male'},
   ...: {'name': 'mei', 'age': '27', 'hometown': '19_street_NY', 'gender': 'female'},
   ...: {'name': 'smith', 'age': '14', 'hometown': '7_street_NY', 'gender': 'male'},
   ...: {'name': 'raj', 'age': '13', 'hometown': '56_street_IND', 'gender': 'male'}]

In [7]: [i for i in a if "hometown" in i and i["hometown"].endswith("NY")]
Out[7]:
[{'name': 'mei', 'age': '27', 'hometown': '19_street_NY', 'gender': 'female'},
 {'name': 'smith', 'age': '14', 'hometown': '7_street_NY', 'gender': 'male'}]
```